# how to do auto build process for eclipse Indigo java Release 2?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, auto-build

I want to create auto build process for the eclipse old version (eclipse Indigo java Release 2) but I am not able to find the process. I want to do auto build for below button .... this button is used for manual build for my project.product

[image]

Some one please help me to do that.

Comment: Indigo is 9 years and 14 releases old, not many people are going to remember how things worked that long ago.

Comment: In the past [PDE Build](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-build/) (which was part of Eclipse and based on Ant) was used to build an Eclipse application, but these days [Maven+Tycho](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) is used to build an Eclipse application.